# Linq to entity order by on selected object that may be null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following query:

```
var ordered = grouped
     .OrderBy(x => x.Spell.SpellStatuses
        .FirstOrDefault(s => !s.NextStatusId.HasValue 
            && s.SpellStatusId == LACompleteStatusId)
        .AddedOn);
```

The above query is selecting a child object from the list and ordering by one of the properties of that object.

The problem is that the child object may be null - which I think will cause an exception when trying to access a property of that object.

I have tried this:

```
s.SpellStatusId == LACompleteStatusId)?.AddedOn
```

But it will not allow null propagation

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can always forgo the one-line approach and write your own IComparer with your rules. Then you can even give it a cool name ;-)

Comment: "But it will not allow null propagation" What do you mean? Do you can an error? if so, what is it?

Comment: how is the propertly declared at the moment? Im thinking that the property is not nullable based on this

Comment: Is it EF query?

Comment: _" which I think will cause an exception when trying to access a property of that object"_ -  does it? Have you tried to run it?

Comment: @SimonPrice it is not the property that is the problem - it is trying to access a property of a null object that is the problem. If FirstOrDefault does not return anything then you cannot access a property from this result

Comment: @GuruStron yes - it is linq, entity framework and linq to entities

Comment: @GuruStron it will run, but will cause an exception when the object returned by FirstOrdefault is null

Comment: @Alex I wonder how it can cause an NRE if this should be just translated to SQL. What version of EF/.NET are you using (isn't it by chance 2.x?)?

Comment: @GuruStron maybe it wont - I just assumed it would. I will test with some data and also output the sql and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work even detailing the code? Something like:

```cs
var ordered = grouped
    .OrderBy(x => {
        var status = x.Spell.SpellStatuses
            .FirstOrDefault(s => !s.NextStatusId.HasValue && s.SpellStatusId == LACompleteStatusId);

        return status == null ? null : status.AddedOn;
    });
```

Comment: this does not work

Comment: @Alex "this does not work" is not very helpful in terms of diagnosing the issue. How exactly it does not work?

Comment: @GuruStron this does not compile

Comment: @kalves a lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree